# setup multi theme configuration in smarty codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, smarty

i have setup the integrated smarty and codeigniter environment by following this manual

```
http://www.coolphptools.com/codeigniter-smarty
```

but i want to setup multi theme using smarty. i know it have to do something with my library `smarty.php`

here is my `smarty.php` file

```
    <?php  if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

/**
 * Smarty Class
 *
 * @package     CodeIgniter
 * @subpackage  Libraries
 * @category    Smarty
 * @author      Kepler Gelotte
 * @link        http://www.coolphptools.com/codeigniter-smarty
 */
require_once( 'libs/Smarty-3.1.16/libs/Smarty.class.php' );

class CI_Smarty extends Smarty {

    function CI_Smarty()
    {
        parent::Smarty();

        $this->compile_dir = APPPATH . "views/templates_c";
        $this->template_dir = APPPATH . "views/templates";
        $this->assign( 'APPPATH', APPPATH );
        $this->assign( 'BASEPATH', BASEPATH );

        log_message('debug', "Smarty Class Initialized");
    }

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->compile_dir = APPPATH . "views/templates_c";
        $this->template_dir = APPPATH . "views/templates";
        $this->assign( 'APPPATH', APPPATH );
        $this->assign( 'BASEPATH', BASEPATH );

        // Assign CodeIgniter object by reference to CI
        if ( method_exists( $this, 'assignByRef') )
        {
            $ci =& get_instance();
            $this->assignByRef("ci", $ci);
        }

        log_message('debug', "Smarty Class Initialized");
    }


    /**
     *  Parse a template using the Smarty engine
     *
     * This is a convenience method that combines assign() and
     * display() into one step. 
     *
     * Values to assign are passed in an associative array of
     * name => value pairs.
     *
     * If the output is to be returned as a string to the caller
     * instead of being output, pass true as the third parameter.
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   string
     * @param   array
     * @param   bool
     * @return  string
     */
    function view($template, $data = array(), $return = FALSE)
    {
        foreach ($data as $key => $val)
        {
            $this->assign($key, $val);
        }

        if ($return == FALSE)
        {
            $CI =& get_instance();
            if (method_exists( $CI->output, 'set_output' ))
            {
                $CI->output->set_output( $this->fetch($template) );
            }
            else
            {
                $CI->output->final_output = $this->fetch($template);
            }
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            return $this->fetch($template);
        }
    }
}
// END Smarty Class
```

which i created for integrating both smarty and codeigniter as specified in manual.

but i am not sure what to edit in this file to enable the multi theme..

what i want know.

1. what should be my directory structure, what is the proper way?
2. what should be edited in my `smarty.php` file so multi theme should work fine.

i have worked in codeigntier for sometime but smarty is new to me.

Comment: Why are you using Smarty? what are the benefits?

Comment: just want to learn smarty. but didnt wanted to miss the MVC part, so i tried both smarty and codeigniter..
why not use smarty? i am using it for first time, and so far i am liking it.. makes alot of work easier, i liked its template inheritance. a nice idea.

anyhow, my problem solved, saw someone posted a code, had to go through his code.
see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved, thanks to someone on github...

```
https://github.com/Vheissu/Ci-Smarty
```

Had to go through the code and, because there was no documentation of how to implement it, it took me sometime to understand.